# Can I combine meta data from a data source to a new column in another data source in Looker Studio

Tags: aggregate, metadata, datasource, looker-studio

I have a google sheet with two columns:
• col1 with unique names (10 unique names)
• col2 with meta data

I have another data source which also contains a column name. I'd like to add the meta data from the first data source (google sheet) to a new column in looker studio.

So from this

| Unique Names | Meta |
| --- | --- |
| Name A | abc |
| Name B | def |
| Name C | ghi |

To this (i only show Name and Meta here as columns, but there are more dimensions in the second data sheet)

| Name | Meta |
| --- | --- |
| Name C | ghi |
| Name C | ghi |
| Name A | abc |
| Name B | def |
| Name A | abc |
| Name A | abc |

Comment: you can blend two tables.